# Magento 1.4.1.1 Import/Export

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I've searched for a working import/export feature/script forever. None of them seems to work.

I'm trying to export, edit and then re-import my stock.

I need the export fields to be sku, store, quantity, is_in_stock and price.

And I want to just re-import the same list of fields.

When I try to use the 'export/import' feature that is built in with Magento, I'm getting a message saying:

`Warning: Please do not close the window during importing/exporting data`

But then the script dies. I've googled this problem and found that a lot of people have it and it's not related to memory/max_execution_time etc..

Can anyone direct me or show me where I can find a working script that will export these fields and then allow me to import them back in?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple answer Magmi It takes a little bit to learn but it's bullet proof and VERY FAST!! And FREE!!!!

https://sourceforge.net/apps/phpwebsite/magmi/

It operates directly on the database and does not bog down your system resources. Also has some really cool plug ins that allow you to do some very fancy things with your images, attributes, Store Categories etc...